# How to Handle Server Crashes for Java Application

Tags: java

I got asked this question for an interview - "what do you do if your server crashes for your Java application?" I gave some answers about trying to follow/decode any error messages that show up but got dinged. I would also think maybe reviewing your code that is related to / handles server connection is a possibility.

Is there some default or standard answer/way to handle this question? It was suggested as a pretty easy question and I haven't been able to find anything particularly standard or definitive in internet search

Comment: First step to handle server crashes is to make sure the server is Highly Available, thus in case of any failures the application will be up and running round the clock. Then once the application is highly available you can move to investigate why the application failed and what can be done to prevent it.

Comment: OK - I just did a quick search of this. I guess that makes sense, but is there anything about that which is specific to Java?

Comment: If your _server_ is crashing, then you have more fundamental architectural problems. I think the only time I've ever managed to actually crash a Java server application I wrote was when I accidentally pulled in a huge dataset into RAM and got an out-of-memory kill. Virtually anything else should be handled by your framework.

Comment: When you say framework - you mean like what is helping you implement the different classes or architecture? Like a Spring Boot or an ORM like Hibernate?

Comment: I dont know if there is a common way to handle this. But at first i would try to make sure that the server boots again (ping to see if it is online) then check if the service is running. if it does not run -> restart it. if it is running check the Logs, in most cases errors can be found there. Then find the cause, fix it and deploy the updated version if possible.

Comment: Thanks springe- I think your answer is probably the best one and most aligned with what I would think is the way to handle this. If you want to make that an answer I will choose it